# Powerbi Variance YTD - Fiscal Year

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery, powerbi-embedded, powerbi-desktop

I am having trouble calculating financial variance by country, its replicating the total value for every country.

My Measures and Fiscal year from JUN - MAY

```
YTD Budget =
CALCULATE (
    SUM ( 'Data'[Expenses] );
    AND (
        Data[Period]
            >= IF ( MONTH (TODAY()) >= 6; MONTH (TODAY()) - 5; MONTH (TODAY ()) + 3 )
                - 4;
        Data[Period]
            <= IF ( MONTH (TODAY()) >= 6; MONTH (TODAY()) - 5; MONTH (TODAY ()) + 3 )
                - 1
    );
    Data[Scenario] = "Budget";
    ALLEXCEPT ( DATA; Data[Scenario] )
)
```

```
YTD Actual =
CALCULATE (
    SUM ( 'Data'[Expenses] );
    AND (
        Data[Period]
            >= IF ( MONTH (TODAY()) >= 6; MONTH (TODAY()) - 5; MONTH (TODAY ()) + 3 )
                - 4;
        Data[Period]
            <= IF ( MONTH (TODAY()) >= 6; MONTH (TODAY()) - 5; MONTH (TODAY ()) + 3 )
                - 1
    );
    Data[Scenario] = "Actual";
    ALLEXCEPT ( DATA; Data[Scenario] )
)
```

```
YTD Var = [YTD Budget] - [YTD Actual] = 1,307
```

```
YTD Var % =
IF (
    [YTD Budget] = 0,
    0,
    ( [YTD Budget] - [YTD Actual] )
        / ABS ( [YTD Budget] )
)
```

My Data set

```
Department Country Class Scenario Month Fiscal Year Expenses

HR Chile Salary Actual Jun FY-2018 8837
HR Chile Salary Actual Jul FY-2018 6288
HR Chile Salary Actual Aug FY-2018 6096
HR Colombia Salary Actual Jun FY-2018 6187
HR Colombia Salary Actual Jul FY-2018 6547
HR Colombia Salary Actual Aug FY-2018 7613
HR Chile Salary Budget Jun FY-2018 6062
HR Chile Salary Budget Jul FY-2018 7491
HR Chile Salary Budget Aug FY-2018 6689
HR Colombia Salary Budget Jun FY-2018 7191
HR Colombia Salary Budget Jul FY-2018 8466
HR Colombia Salary Budget Aug FY-2018 6976
```

```
YTD- Actual: 41,568.00 
YTD- Budget: 42,875.00
```

Expect Outcome:

```
Country     Var($)          Var%
Chile       -979 
Colombia    2,286
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add to your YTD Actual and YTD Budget in ALLEXCEPT filter, the Data[Country], the YTD Var will get the values you are expecting:

```
YTD Actual2 = 
CALCULATE (
    SUM ( 'Data'[Expenses] );
    AND (
        Data[Period]
            >= IF ( MONTH (TODAY()) >= 6; MONTH (TODAY()) - 5; MONTH (TODAY ()) + 3 )
                - 4;
        Data[Period]
            <= IF ( MONTH (TODAY()) >= 6; MONTH (TODAY()) - 5; MONTH (TODAY ()) + 3 )
                - 1
    );
    Data[Scenario] = "Actual";
    ALLEXCEPT ( DATA; Data[Scenario];Data[Country] )
)
```

You can also add a new calculated column to get the values of YTD Var by country:

```
YTD Var = Calculate (sum(Data[YTD Budget2]))-Calculate (sum(Data[YTD Actual2]))
```

[image]

Is this result you need?